# Get all days of any month with objective-c

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsdate

A seemingly simple question...how can I return a list of days for any specified month?

```
NSDate *today = [NSDate date]; //Get a date object for today's date
NSCalendar *c = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
NSRange days = [c rangeOfUnit:NSDayCalendarUnit 
                       inUnit:NSMonthCalendarUnit 
                      forDate:today];
```

I basically want to use that, but replace `today` with say, the month of January, so I can return all of those days

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Carl's answer works on Mac. The following works on Mac or iPhone (no `dateWithNaturalLanguageString:` available there).

```
NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
NSDateComponents *components = [[[NSDateComponents alloc] init] autorelease];

// Set your year and month here
[components setYear:2015];
[components setMonth:1];

NSDate *date = [calendar dateFromComponents:components];
NSRange range = [calendar rangeOfUnit:NSCalendarUnitDay inUnit:NSCalendarUnitMonth forDate:date];

NSLog(@"%d", (int)range.length);
```

Comment: Thanks. Original poster didn't specify, so I wasn't sure.

Comment: yeah...my bad. Should have specified :(

Comment: What if I wanted to go a step further and use a date formatter and loop through each one of those days and return for instance, "Thursday 17th"

Comment: Not sure I understand, but I think you're saying you have an NSDate from an NSDateFormatter. You want to get the NSDateComponents via NSCalendar's componentsFromDate method, passing NSWeekdayCalendarUnit(Thurs) and NSDayCalendarUnit (17) as the flags.

Comment: Picture this scenario: you have a table view listing out all of the months of the year. When you choose April, a new tableview is presented with all of the days of April, formatted as such "Monday, 1" "Tuesday, 2" etc.

Comment: in this code what will  happened to  a february in leap year ?

Comment: Given that you specify a date which sets the context for the rangeOfUnit:inUnit:forDate method, I assume it does the right thing (returns 1-29). Try it and verify!

Comment: Actually, in this example year 0001 is used.  In order to get the proper value for February in a leap year, the year needs to be set in comps properly.

Comment: Note that month ranges from 1 to 12 in the above code, not from 0 to 11.

Answer (score 2):

You can make your date with pretty much any string:

```
NSDate *date = [NSDate dateWithNaturalLanguageString:@"January"];
```

Then the rest of your code will work as-is to give you back the `NSRange` for the number of days in January.