# How can i know the number of days of a month?

Tags: iphone

Using a `NSCalendar` os anything else, is it possible to get the number of days of the month of a given `NSDate` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Get all days of any month with objective-c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1731322/get-all-days-of-any-month-with-objective-c)

Duplicate from there apparently, anyways, I'll keep this here.

```
NSCalendar* a = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
NSDateComponents* b = [[[NSDateComponents alloc] init] autorelease];
[b setMonth:1]; // The Month
NSRange c = [a rangeOfUnit:NSDayCalendarUnit
                          inUnit:NSMonthCalendarUnit
                         forDate:[a dateFromComponents:b]];
// c.length will have the amount of days
```