# Convert date from mysql to NSDate

Tags: ios, nsdate

I have a varchar in mysql that holds dates. I have been trying to convert it into an `NSDate`, but nothing I have tried yet works. The `NSString` from mysql looks like this:

August 11, 2012, 10:17 AM

All the posts so far relating to `NSString` to `NSDate` conversions have not yet worked for this string. If someone could please help...

Answer (score 2):

I assume you use JSON for getting data from MySQL(server) and have a JSON object called myJSONObject

**`NOTE:`** `myJSONObject` must be serialized using some framework like [NSJSONSerialization](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSJSONSerialization_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

**EDIT with some detailed question links**

You have asked to convert data to **August 11, 2012, 10:17 AM** but my sample code tries to convert as **2012-08-11 10:17:..**, i edited my sample code for you. For more, take a look at [NSDateFormatter](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

**ATTENTION PLEASE:** you can get the variable `month_from_date` using [NSDateComponents](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateComponents_Class/Reference/Reference.html). There are some questions about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3694867/nsdate-get-year-month-day) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1731322/get-all-days-of-any-month-with-objective-c).. If you can't, please open a new post.

```
 NSString* dateString = [myJSONObject objectForKey:@"date"];

            NSDateFormatter* fmt = [NSDateFormatter new];
            [fmt setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone]]; 
           // [fmt setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];
           [fmt setDateFormat:@"%@ DD,YYYY, HH:mm",month_from_date]; 
           NSDate* dateFromString = [fmt dateFromString:dateString];
NSLog("Here is date from string: %@",dateFromString);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I parse the json similar to the way you posted. I put in the code and still get null however. It could be that the dateformat is wrong- Again, Friday, August 3, 2012, 11:20 AM - is what needs to be converted.

Answer (score 2):

to convert a `NSString` into a `NSDate`, please, use the `NSDateFormatter`.

```
NSString *_dateString = @"August 11, 2012, 10:17 AM";
NSDateFormatter *_dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[_dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MMMM dd, yyyy, HH:mm a"];
NSDate *_date = [_dateFormatter dateFromString:_dateString];
NSLog(@"raw date : %@", _date);
NSLog(@"formatted date : %@", [_dateFormatter stringFromDate:_date]);
```

the output `NSDate` will contains the date:

```
raw date : 2012-08-10 23:17:00 +0000
formatted date : August 11, 2012, 11:17 AM
```

you can format the `NSDate` as you'd like for a different output, it is up to up now, but you can work with the `NSDate` object which contains the date.

***NOTE:** we don't know the timezone from the input date when we are converting it, so the `NSDate` using the defaults for it. if you set the current timezone you will get the correct date after conversion.*

Comment: but he wants to get August not 08 for example

Comment: he wrote the _input_ string is `August 11, 2012, 10:17 AM` and he likes to convert into `NSDate` as _output_. did I misunderstand something?

Comment: your output will give 08, 2012 but he wants August, 2012. Not an important point but there must be some enumerations for this. my answer explains a little

Comment: @ilis, I understand what my output is. I've said I still guess he wants to convert the date **from** that format, not **to** that format. however, for the same output he could use the same `NSDateFormatter` as in my answer with the `-stringFromDate:` method, if he really wants that output, what you assume. I'll update to my answer for it.

Comment: @@holex, this time when i read the question i really couldnt understand what he wants. He says "a varchar in mysql that holds dates. I have been trying to convert it into an NSDate. The NSString from mysql looks like this:

August 11, 2012, 10:17 AM" but in the second paragparh i think he wants NSString from NSDate.. I'm not sure from now on

Comment: @ilis, on my screen in the last section he mentions: `NSString` _to_ `NSDate` _conversions_, this is why I thinks he wants conversion **from** that input `NSString` to `NSDate`, but we will see what he says. :)

Comment: @ilis I don't know the truth now. :) I've just read the title of the thread, it says _Convert date **from** mysql **to** `NSDate`_ but I'm confused now.

Comment: you are welcome, @DanielShaffer! :) please, don't forget to upvote and accept the answer, if you think it was helpful.

Comment: hey guys, what was the thing exactly asked here, i haven't get it yet:))

Comment: @ilis, what was your question then? you've asked a `NSString` to `NSDate` conversion...

Comment: but from the question it is not clear if he asks for NSString to NSDate or vice versa

Comment: @ilis, oh sorry! :( for a second I though you are the asker. :) yes, perhaps he is still enjoying the solution and he forgot us. :D in most of the cases it happens.

Comment: :) i see. i'm aware of the solution but really this question made me go crazy(like Sheldon Cooper when can't understand a complicated mathematic formula or a series of Star Wars:)